# high frequency from low frequency clock

Tags: vhdl, clock, fpga, spartan

My spartan 3a fpga board has a 50mhz clock while implementing a microblaze with ram ddr2 , it required a frequency of 62mhz which was edited by my program , when asked about this , they told me that 60mhz clock is used to generate other clocks internally but how does a 50mhz clock produce a 62mhz clock which is higher !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are built in technologies that multiply the clock to higher frequencies. See [Frequency Multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_multiplier) and [Phase Locked Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop)

Answer (score 4):

in Xilinx Spartan devices you can use so called DCMs (digital clock managers) that give you a whole lot of possibilities; see [Spartan User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug331.pdf) or [Xilinx Spartan 3 DCM](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp462.pdf). with the synthesizer option, clock multiplication/division is possible.

Answer (score 0):

under your design name in Implementation window in ISE right click and add new sorce select IPcore then select clocking wizard you can enter the primary freq : 50 mhz and required out freq: 62 mhz and the core generator will do it for you.